# how to wait for angular http method to complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my function for getting data from server

```
function getAll_Tables() {
  $scope.tableList = [];
  $http({
    method : 'GET',
    url : '/abc/GetTables',
    headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
  }).success(function(data) {
      $('#T_LoaderSpinner').hide();
      if (data.StatusCode === 101) {
        if (data.Data != null) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
            $scope.tableList.push(data.Data[i]);
          }
        }
      } else {
        alert("We could not process your request......Please try later.")
      }
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      $('#T_LoaderSpinner').hide();
      alert("We could not process your request......Please try later.")
    });
}
```

and my another function to use that data is :

```
$scope.load_policy = function(id, type) {
  $scope.getRuleList();
  getAll_ScoringTables(); 
  alert(JSON.stringify($scope.tableList));
}
```

My tableList is not get updated - how to get updated tableList here?

Comment: Can you explain more? Is the table not populating the data from the backend? Or you want to do some performance on the data, but it does not change? It will be better if you can make a `jsfiddle` link to produce the problem.

Comment: Your tableList probably is updated, but not when you alert it. Your getAll_ScoringTables does an async $http call and your alert does not wait for that to finish

Comment: Yes devqon .... but how to wait for updated result in alert...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `getAll_Tables()` is asynchronous, so in the function that uses it, when you do the `alert` the data hasn't been fetched yet. You need to wait for this promise to complete. I would suggest the following changes:

```
function getAll_Tables() {
  $scope.tableList = [];
  return $http({ // ADDED RETURN HERE
    method : 'GET',
    url : '/abc/GetTables',
    headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
  }).success(function(data) {
      $('#T_LoaderSpinner').hide();
      if (data.StatusCode === 101) {
        if (data.Data != null) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
            $scope.tableList.push(data.Data[i]);
          }
          return; // ADDED RETURN HERE
        }
      } else {
        alert("We could not process your request......Please try later.")
      }
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      $('#T_LoaderSpinner').hide();
      alert("We could not process your request......Please try later.")
    });
}
```

So here we're returning the `$http` function out of `getAll_Tables()`, so we can `.then` it in the other function, or in other words, wait until the request is complete before continuing with the code inside the `.then` function.

```
$scope.load_policy = function(id, type) {
  $scope.getRuleList();
  getAll_ScoringTables()
  .then(function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.tableList)); // tableList has the correct data now
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

here is a more comfortable way, use promoises

```
var promise1 = $http({method: 'GET', url: 'a/pi-one-url', cache: 

'true'});
var promise2 = $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api-two-url', cache: 'true'});

$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(data){
    console.log(data[0], data[1]);
});
```

Comment: +1 to this - if `$scope.getRuleList();` is also asynchronous, you should definitely go with this answer.

Comment: I am agree with your answer but in my scenerio , i am using getAll_Tables() at multiple places... then i have to update code at all places.

Answer (score 1):

You would either need to return the http request, and simply handle the success inside your load policy, or you could use a callback to call an anonymous function that gets called from your success method. This would then call your anonymous function after the success went through

```
function getAll_Tables(callback) { 
    $scope.tableList = [];
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/abc/GetTables',
        headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
    }).success(function(data) { 
        $('#T_LoaderSpinner').hide();
        callback();
    }).error(function(data) { 
        $('#T_LoaderSpinner').hide();
        alert("We could not process your request......Please try later.")
    });
}  

$scope.load_policy = function(id, type) { 
    $scope.getRuleList(function() {
        getAll_ScoringTables(); 
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.tableList));
    });
}
```

So one of the other options would be

```
function getAll_Tables(callback) { 
    $scope.tableList = [];
    return $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/abc/GetTables',
        headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
    });
}  

$scope.load_policy = function(id, type) { 
    $scope.getRuleList.success(function() {
        getAll_ScoringTables(); 
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.tableList));
    }).error(function() {
        alert('failed');
    });
}
```

Comment: @sumitchoudhary You could send the data back as a parameter of the callback and then handle it in your callback (or in the success function in the 2nd example)